# How to solve these children's coding puzzles

Tags: visual

I was looking through a children's book of puzzles and realised I couldn't solve some of them!  Can anyone tell me how to solve these two puzzles? For the first one the options are:

- FX, HX, HV, FV, GZ

and for the second puzzle they are:

- GM, EO, GL, EL, FN

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard... I would need more examples to be sure of my pattern, but here is what I got for the first one.

> HX
>  The first letter is associated to the number of loops in the cloud.
>  6 = F, 5 = I, 4 = H and 3 = G
>  The Second letter depends on the most important circle inside.
>  If there is a greyed out circle, X, else if there is a black circle, Z, if only white circles, V.

Here is what I got for the second one.

> EL
> The first letter is the state of the biggest square. E = Cross, F = *F*ull, H = *H*alf, G = *G*rid
> The second letter is the position of the small square. Up left = L, Up Right = M, Down left = G, Down right = N

Do I sound stupid? Somehow it seems to make sense to me...

Comment: For the first puzzle, couldn't the 2nd letter be based on the number of black dots?  1=Z, 2=X, and 0=V?

Comment: @ElGuapo I guess it could. Part of the reason why I feel I need more examples to confirm my pattern. Any more complex or abstract solution would probably not be suited for children... I would really appreciate if the OP posted his sources... This seems pretty hard for children.

Comment: @stackreader These are literally the questions. It's from a book to prepare children for a test they do when they are 11.

Comment: @stackreader I can give you some different questions in the same style, if that is what you meant?

Comment: @Anush When I said to post your sources, I meant the name of the book. You are not the creator of the puzzle so you have to declare your sources. Also, does that book have the answers?

Comment: @Anush as for the questions, they are fine as is. I was just saying that there are not enough cases in the question to prove my patterns, which only mean that my answer is not solid enough... probably.